# Async ApplicationListener in Spring compared with async @EventListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, events, event-listener

Since Annotation-Driven Event Listener was added in Spring version 4.2, to make an asynchronous event listener it is only needed to add the `@Async` annotation to the public method annotated with `@EventListener`.

```
@Component
public class AnnotationDrivenContextStartedListener {

    @Async
    @EventListener
    public void handleContextStart(ContextStartedEvent cse) {
        System.out.println("Handling context started event.");
    }

}
```

The question is the following. Could the `@Async` annotation be added to the `onApplicationEvent` method of a traditional `ApplicationListener` to achieve the same functionality? Or should we define a new bean for the `ApplicationEventMulticaster` to handle all events in async way?

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringEventListener implements ApplicationListener<CustomSpringEvent> {

    @Async
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomSpringEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received spring custom event - " + event.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I have tried it and it works correctly, but I am not sure if it is a good practice or can cause problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't do that, it's a valid usage.

Comment: I ask this simply because in all the examples I see about Spring events on Internet, the Async is always tied to the @EventListener annotation and there aren't many examples of the other option (the oldest one). Even in the Spring documentation there is no example of this. Thank you for your time.